# MongoDB - Equivalent of LEFT JOIN where one collection isn't exists

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Is there an equivalent to LEFT JOIN query where right collection isn't exists in MongoDB?

SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM TableA as A LEFT JOIN TableB as B ON A.id = B.id 
WHERE B.Id IS NULL
```

MongoDB: `???`

*P.S.:* My initial sketch:

```
db.getCollection('collA').aggregate([
    {
      $lookup:
        {
          from: "collB",
          localField: "_id",
          foreignField: "_id",
          as: "collB"
        }           
   }
   //, {$match : collB is empty}
])
```

Comment: The statement is exactly what [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) does, since the "left" is always retained but the items populated to the target array are **only** those that match from the joined collection. Are you perhaps asking how to completely exclude the source ( "left" ) collection when the resulting array of `$lookup` is empty? Which is actually not the same as the SQL presented here.

Comment: @NeilLunn Yes, You understood me well. But my sql-query is correct. I have two collections with same ids but first collection has additional documents. I want to retrieve this additional documents.

Comment: From "collB" that do not match "collA"? Is that the question? Or from "collA"? Because you are actually being told that with "collA" this is exactly what `$lookup` does.

Comment: From `collA` that do not match `collB`. `$lookup` retrieves all documents from `collA` and appends appropriate documents from `collB`. In other words, I want to retrieve documents from `collA` WITHOUT appended  documents from `collB`.

Comment: That's what I thought you meant and was the last part of the first comment I left.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well your edit basically has the answer. Simply `$match` where the array is empty:

```js
db.getCollection('collA').aggregate([
    { "$lookup": {
      "from": "collB",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "collB"
    }},
   { "$match": { "collB.0": { "$exists": false } } }
])
```

The [`$exists`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/) test on the array index of `0` is the most efficient way to ask in a query "is this an array with items in it".

Comment: Thanks, I think your answer is right but i can try it after a few hours.

Comment: @Palindromer Well the case is pretty simple at what I was originally getting at in the comment. When you `$lookup` the result is an array with the documents that "matched" the given keys. If there is no match at all, then the array is empty. So we just test for "empty", and that technique has been around for a long time. We could also `$redact` with `$size` on the array, but that's really overkill when a simple query condition will do.

Comment: is it possible to add additional filters to both collections, like I want this join query work the same way, but only on specific subset of both tables where collA.code == collB.code == 'some_value'

Comment: @NeilLunn See If you could solve this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68668121/mongodb-aggregate-query-lookup-comparing-null-localfield-value-results-in-slow

Answer (score 0):

Neil Lunn's solution is working, but I have another approach, because 
$lookup pipe does not support Shard collection in the "from" statement.

So I used to use simple java script as follows. It's simple and easy to modify. But for performance you should have proper indexes!

```
var mycursor = db.collA.find( {}, {_id: 0, myId:1} ) 

mycursor.forEach( function (x){ 
    var out = db.collB.count( { yourId : x.myId } )
    if ( out > 0) {
        print('The id exists! ' + x.myId); //debugging only

        //put your other query in  here....

        }
} )
```