# Needed mongodb query to check whether date is between two Dates stored in collection document

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean

my document sample

```
schema name -> Doctor_Availabilty

{
"DoctorID" : "32c262a5-6ae7-427d-ba01-095d49e2e929",
"Start_Date" : ISODate("2018-03-19T18:30:00.000Z"),
"End_Date" : ISODate("2018-03-25T18:29:59.999Z")
}
```

I want to perform mongodb operation to check Whether Doctor is Available on somedate(Mar 24, 2018) for patient booking an appointment???

I have referred all mongodb operator but there is no operator for isBetween(like of momentjs) in mongodb.

Comment: You can use use left join where null value reference https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398842/mongodb-equivalent-of-left-join-where-one-collection-isnt-exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [$lte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/), [$gte](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) and [$and](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/and/#op._S_and) operators

```
Doctor_Availabilty.find({
  $and: [{
    Start_Date: {
      $lte: someDate,
    },
  }, {    
    End_Date: {
      $gte: someDate,
    },
  }],
});
```

Comment: thanks worked for me