# How to remove a document from a collection if it has not been referred to by any other document

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I have two collections in my MongoDB database:

1. Clubs collection
2. Photos collection.

Their schemas are as follows:

```js
var clubsSchema = new Schema({
  clubName: { type: String },
  photosOfMembers: [{ type: ObjectId, ref:'Photos' }],
});

var photosSchema = new Schema({
  sourceUrl: { type: String },
  filePath: { type: String },
  description: { type: String }
});
```

There are ***many*** clubs in our school.
The photos are profile pictures of students.
Some students belong to ***more than one*** club, and therefore, multiple clubs can refer to a single photo.

These photos are fetched from an external website(eg Facebook, Reddit, Quora), recorded in the database and the file stored in the server.

Each time a student joins a club, we crawl for their photo from the external website.
We use the photosSchema.sourceUrl to check if the photo exists in our database, and then we store it if it doesn't exist.
This helps us to prevent a situation of duplicate images belonging one student.

This works fine.

The problem comes when a student leaves a club.

---

> - The Problem:

---

I want to delete the photo of that student when he/she is no longer a member of any club. If he/she belongs to a club the photo remains.

My database has thousands of records - what is the best(most effective/efficient) way to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MongoDB - Equivalent of LEFT JOIN where one collection isn't exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44398842/mongodb-equivalent-of-left-join-where-one-collection-isnt-exists)

Answer (score 0):

1. When he/she is leaving the club, u must be updating clubs collection right. So while updating the clubs collection u can get the object id of that student photo. And then u can search in clubs collection if the same object id is not mapped to any other club, then delete that document from photos collection.
2. The second way that i can think of is by using lookup. But the first one seems to be more simpler